# Configurable Product Option appears in drop down even though it is out of stock

Tags: configurable-product, stock

No matter what I try, in one of my store views, all product options are appearing in the drop down menu, even though all but one are sold out (only Size UK 10 should be available. All others have quantity 0 and are marked Out of Stock).

[image: In this store, configurable options show as in stock]

On other store views, it appears correctly:
[image: This is how it should appear]

As you can see, the product is out of stock on the magento back end:
[image]

Here is an example of one of the simple products:
[image]

I've tried looking to see if there is a discrepancy between the different store views, but can't see anything. Does anyone have any ideas of what I can try?

(Running 1.7.0.2 Magento CE)

Comment: Just to get it out of the way...did you rebuild your indexes? Also check if you have any extensions installed that might change something regarding the configurable products.

Comment: Yes I've done this. It is not anything obvious like indexes or caches.

Answer (score 0):

Willster, i can be issue with Simple product store selection.

```
Goto Admin>Catalog>Manage Product >Select the Child products
Goto Website ,here you get list of website,Select all web site
```

[image]
after that `indexing the  from Index Manegement`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'd already checked this and all websites had been selected for the simple products.